# Rails warehouse app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design

I am building a Warehouse app. I want to see the current Stock data (replenishments - sales) for each location in locations/index. Now I have a calculation in the model to do this, but it takes a long time to calculate each time I load the locations/index page.

What is the best way to organise tables to persist stock data in database and nor recalculate everything each time I open a page?

Here is my schema:
[image]

My idea is to add a Stock Stock table that would recalculate in the background when a Replenishment / Sale is created. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this doesn't have one correct way. But here's my take.

You can have a one-to-one between `location` and `stock`, and a has_many :through between `stock` and `product`. You probably want to capture the price/cost here as different `product` at different time can have different prices, so you need to make use of the join table. This way you can calculate the correct price/cost. (You might want to add `cost` to `product` if it's relavent). Similarly I think you need to add a `cost` column to `replenishment` to capture to cost at the time of replenishment, and a `price` column to `sale` to capture the price at the time of sale.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simplified, and may have errors as I have not tested it.

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :location
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :stocks

  #product stock in all locations
  def total_stock
    stocks.sum(:quantity)
  end
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks

  #stock of all products in this location
  def total_stock
    stocks.sum(:quantity)
  end
end

class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Replenishment < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :stock
end
```

You must update the quantity in the Stock model each time you create, modify or delete sales or replenishments. Or you can have a background job to update quantities periodically.

You could do the same in Location and Product models. You could add a quantity attribute and update it after each sale or replenishment, or use a background job. In this case you do not need the "total_stock" methods.